# Range Parameter Application-Defined or Object-Defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a short function that is basically `vlookup` 2.0.

It needs to find multiple instances of a value and return multiple values as one string.

The data set has a list of codes (one of which is passed as a parameter) that it will look for in a range (passed as a parameter). Then it goes down the range - if the code matches the value at `(x,A)` it concatenates the values at `(x, e)` and `(x, i)` to the string "locations".

My issue is with the range passed as parameter. When using "watch" to inspect the variable, most of the values give the error:

> application-defined or object-defined error.

I have a sinking feeling this is just a syntax problem. I've tried using ranges both on the same sheet as the function being called and on a different sheet and neither have produced a result.

```
Function findLoc(code As String, searchArr As Variant) As String
    Dim locations As String    
    Dim x As Integer           
    Dim search As Variant

    Set search = searchArr
    locations = ""

    For x = 1 To search.Rows.Count     
        If search.Cells(RowIndex = x, ColumnIndex = "A").Value = code Then     
            locations = locations & search.Cells(RowIndex = x, ColumnIndex = "E").Value & _
              " in " & search.Cells(RowIndex = x, ColumnIndex = "I").Value & ", "                           
        End If
    Next

    findLoc = locations
End Function
```

The expected result should be something along the lines of "5 in Westeros, 2 in Black Mesa". Locations have been changed to protect the innocent.

So far I've been unable to even see if the code is working - all I get is `#VALUE` as a result in Excel.

---

```
Function findLoc(code As String, ByVal searchArr As range) As String
    Dim locations As String
    Dim x As Long

    locations = ""

    For x = 1 To searchArr.Rows.Count
        If Not IsError(searchArr.Cells(RowIndex:=x, ColumnIndex:="A").Value = 
            code) Then

                   locations = Location & searchArr.Cells(RowIndex:=x, 
                       ColumnIndex:="E").Value & " in " & 
                       search.Cells(RowIndex:=x, ColumnIndex:="I").Value & ", "
        End If
    Next

    findLoc = locations

End Function
```

Comment: First `Dim x As Long`, since it's iterating rows and worksheets can have many times more rows than 32,767. Next, why declare your ranges `As Variant` instead of `As Range`? Variant is making every single one of these member calls late-bound, which is making your life much harder than it needs to be. Try invoking the function from the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) - what error do you get, and where?

Comment: `search` is purely redundant, too, and note that the `Range.Value = something` comparison will throw a *type mismatch* if the cell whose value is being compared to that `code As String` value is actually a cell error. Use `IfError` to determine if the comparison is legal first.

Comment: this looks suspect and does not compile when I use Option Explicit: `search.Cells(RowIndex = x, ColumnIndex = "A").Value`

Comment: Should be specified like: `search.Cells(RowIndex:=x, ColumnIndex:="A").Value` or simply `search.Cells(x, "A").Value`.

Comment: Calling the function in the immediate pane gives me "Compile Error: Expected: list separator or )", though I'm unsure if that means I'm using the immediate window incorrectly.

Comment: Mathieu, could you also please elaborate on utilizing `IfError` in this context?

Comment: The compile error is probably due to the malformed named argument `:=` operators. Sorry I meant `IsError`, not `IfError` - you'd use it like `If Not IsError(searchArr.Cells(...).Value) Then`, and then comparisons are only safe inside that conditional block.

Comment: That said you'll want to rename `searchArr`, declare it `As Range`, pass it `ByVal`, and validate that it's in the shape you're expecting - contiguous, 9 columns wide, etc.

Comment: I am still getting a compile error, even after changing the named argument operators, adding IsError, and updating searchArr to be `ByVal searchArr As range`.  Would it help to post my now updated code?
Thank you so much for all your help, by the way!

Comment: Yes please post updated code.

Comment: Your code is riddled with errors, hard to know if just typos. Either way use 'Option Explicit'. `search` is not defined, `coulumn`... And you've misunderstood MG's point - check the cell contents is not an error and then check if it equals `code`.